# How to hide the contents of the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 tabs, each tab contains different data. When I click on the checkbox, the corresponding tab is shown.But when I uncheck, the tab is invisible but the contents are not invisible. How to solve this problem?
My page is

```
<style>
    .ui-state-disabled {
    display: none;
}
</style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 2,
    "disabled": [1,2,3]
  });

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
     $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val() );
    }
    else{
         $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
    }
});
});
</script>
```

.

```
<body>
 <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nithin</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Vipin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Sachin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Ganguly</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Nithin</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Vipin</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Sachin</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-4">
    <p>Ganguly</p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-1" value="1">tabs-1 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-2" value="2">tabs-2 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-3" value="3">tabs-3 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-4" value="4">tabs-4 
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the working code on http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/12/

Comment: `the tab is invisible but the contents is not invisible.`.....?

Comment: you are just disabling the tab, you aren't hiding the content at all ?? just make sure you hide the content as well and show only relavant content.

Comment: @Nithu i think you didn't correctly defined your question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/22/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 0,
    "disabled": [1,2,3]
  });

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
     $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val() );
    }
    else{
        $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
        var tab = $(this);
        $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(":checked").first().val());
        //$('#tabs').tabs("select", $(":checked").last().val());
        //It is based on you what to use. (first or last selected value)
    }
});
});
```

I hope this helps.
Regards

Comment: It working only in fiddle.My page shows nothing

Comment: then go and check your code, if it doesn't matches jsfiddle ?

Comment: there must be some issue in your code :( it must work if it is working in fiddle :(

Comment: I copied the code you mentioned but not working properly. Only tab is hidden. contents is there

Comment: @Nithu, the content of the previous tab will be shown.

Comment: Your code is correct.I saw in the fiddle,but I don't know whats the real mistake

Comment: i did my best bro, at least if it is not working on your system then you are missing some thing or you are doing some thing wrong. Go double check your code and let me know. Regards

Comment: Sure friend..I will find it out

Comment: It is not correct. If the previous tab is not checked, your code do wrong (it shows and unchecked tab)

Comment: @MIIB if the pervious tab is not checked text must be shown (did you checked the JSFiddle provided by the questioner) there was already text provided before the tab was there ?? did you understood the question at all ?

Comment: @X-Factor Good solution though.

Comment: @X-Factor:- The code is worked but onloading the first tab shows the content of the 3rd.

Comment: @Nithu i updated JSFiddle check it out http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/29/, and edited the code as well just select it as per your requirement.

Comment: @x-factor- When I click on that checkbox I don't want activate that tab.If I want that tab I will take it on mouse click.

Comment: something like this @Nithu http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/30/

Comment: Thank you man X-factor... You are so helpful

Comment: @Nithu we are here to help :) Regards

Comment: @X-Factor- you must check this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219957/how-to-assign-the-text-boxes-in-a-specified-manner

Answer (score 3):

Just check the `else` portion ...   **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/28/)**

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 2,
    "disabled": [1,2,3]
  });

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
     $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val() );
    }
    else{
        // $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
        $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
         $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).prev().val());
         $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).prev().val());
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
     $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val() );
    }
    else{
         $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
      $("#tabs-"+$(this).val()).children().hide());
    }
});
```

you just disable tab.Hide the contant also

Comment: this will hide all the text, and will not show the previous shown text :(

Answer (score 2):

May be this could help:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
        $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val());
        $('[id="' + this.name + '"]').find('p').show();
    } else {
        $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
        $('[id="' + this.name + '"]').find('p').hide();
    }
});
```

### Note:

No need to add a `content` class.

[**just checkout the fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/26/)

Comment: But when I hide the tab,the content also hidden.But there is also missing the  contents of other tab

Comment: @Nithu Just updated the answer and the fiddle try this out.

Answer (score 2):

Add `var hhh = $("input:checked").val();
        $('#tabs').tabs("enable", hhh);
     $('#tabs').tabs("select", hhh );
     $("#tabs-"+hhh+" p").show();` to your else.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhs5p/2/)

```
                $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 2,
    "disabled": [1,2,3]
  });

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
     $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val() );
     $("#tabs-"+$(this).val()+" p").show();
    }
    else{
         $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
        $("#tabs-"+$(this).val()+" p").hide();
        var hhh = $("input:checked").val();
        $('#tabs').tabs("enable", hhh);
     $('#tabs').tabs("select", hhh );
     $("#tabs-"+hhh+" p").show();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: But when I hide the tab,the content also hidden.But there is also missing the contents of other tab

Comment: I've edited the code and the jsfiddle link. Now it's working

Comment: @MIIB-pls check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224642/one-to-many-relationships-in-compoundjs

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
      $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
        "selected": 2,
        "disabled": [1,2,3]
      });

    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
         $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val() );
        }
        else{
             $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
             $('#'+$(this).attr('name')).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But when I hide the tab,the content also hidden.But there is also missing the contents of other tab

Answer (score 1):

add class `ui-state-disabled`  in else part to the element then it will `display: none;`