# How to arrange the textboxes in a common style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have got a task to create the code for aligning the text boxes. I have a main div.Inside that I have so many sub div. These sub div is not properly aligned.I want to align these div by using jquery without editing the sub div.How can I do this?
My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Jquery-Align</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
 $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
});//]]>  

</script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nithin</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Vipin</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="maindiv">
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Age:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Vipin</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

You can see my code on http://jsfiddle.net/CG6Vw/

Comment: why not use tables ??

Comment: do you mean dont use css?

Comment: We don't use tables.. This will be generated by scaffolding.So it will come on a div

Comment: @albert -we can use the css.But the these css will manage the all textboxes. The text boxes are generated by scaffolding.We don't want to edit it.

Comment: use @dfsq's answer.....exactly what i was going to do

Comment: For example in that example there is so many space in the right side.We can utilize that space by putting the text boxes there also.

Comment: @albert- This is ok. But you can see the space on right side.I want to two textboxes on one raw

Comment: Plz have a look for two text boxes : http://jsfiddle.net/CG6Vw/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `min-width` to label

```
#maindiv div{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 6px 8px 0
}
#maindiv b{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:80px; 
    width:auto
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CG6Vw/8/)

Comment: If there is no tag b. How to get the label

Comment: @Nithu write label tag. <label>Age:</label> and css #maindiv label{..}

Comment: @Sowmya-I used that but when a large name comes the position is not in proper mode.. Pls check here http://jsfiddle.net/Tbter/

Comment: there is nothing at right side.. free space.. So we can not arrange it vertically

Answer (score 2):

Everything should be done with proper tool. Just use super simple CSS for your task:

```
#maindiv > div {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#maindiv > div > b {
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CG6Vw/1/

Comment: yep.This is ok. But you can see the space on right side.I want to two textboxes on one raw

Comment: If there is no tag b. How to get the label

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it seems okay as per your requirement --

[Tabber](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use css, you can also do that using jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#maindiv > div > b').each(function(){
         $(this).attr('style','width: 60px; display: inline-block;');
    });
});
```

But again you are still using style :)

Comment: yep.This is ok. But you can see the space on right side.I want to two textboxes on one raw

Comment: If there is no tag b. How to get the label

Comment: replace b with label `$('#maindiv > div > label')`  http://jsfiddle.net/CG6Vw/12/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this bro : [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CG6Vw/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nithin</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Vipin</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="maindiv">
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="field" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Age:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="field" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="field" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="field" />
        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Vipin</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
label, input[type="text"]{
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
label
{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.field{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:5px 0px;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
    var max = 0;
    $("label").each(function(){
        if ($(this).width() > max)
            max = $(this).width();    
    });
    $("label").width(max);
});
```

Comment: Here We can reduce the text box size and also align two text boxes together

Comment: i think you should concern with this [plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/), which will arrange all the textbox and other elements according to space available

Comment: @X-Factor-check this link also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224642/one-to-many-relationships-in-compoundjs

Comment: @X-Factor- Do you know anything about responsive design

Comment: @Nithu yes, there are so many ways of responsive design. Which one are you talking about ? CSS Or JQuery.

Comment: @X-Factor--Both are possible. I am new in this.So can you share some articles or show some examples in jsfiddle

Comment: @Nithu http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design, http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/a-look-at-responsive-css-frameworks, and the best of all http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design

Comment: @X-Factor- Thanx. Hope you have sample examples also for the phone conversion.

Comment: @Nithu I haven't. Try a little yourself.

Comment: @X-Factor- pls check this link http://jsfiddle.net/ucpcA/17/.. Here I want a line at startng when I select the menu home